# javascript exercise - recursive function with a string

Tags: javascript, recursion

console.log( ‘blah’.repeatMe( 3 ) );

Using Javascript write the code that would make the previous function print:

Output: blahblahblah

Comment: Sorry, no free codez.

Comment: What have you tried? What did not work?  Can you do it without the syntactic sugar of attaching the method to strings directly?

Comment: Sounds like homework to me.  What have you tried?  Where did you get stuck?  Can you ask a more specific question about a piece of the solution rather than just ask us to write the code for you?

Comment: Hey guys, this was an exercise I saw into a test. I ask how to solve it in order to find anyone who is interested in just shows up this solution for fun.

Answer (score 1):

Oh, it's too fun to pass up a functional style solution.

```js
String.prototype.repeatMe = function(n) {
    if (n <= 0) return "";
    if (n%2 === 1) return (""+this) + this.repeatMe(n-1);

    var half = this.repeatMe(n/2);
    return half + half;
}

document.body.innerHTML = "tester".repeat(10)
```

I'll let you work out what's happening as an exercise.

Comment: Thank you very much Lye. It's very fun to analize your solution.